# Why $\textrm{tr}(\mu_1 \Sigma_2 \mu_1 - 2\mu_1^T \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2 + \mu_2 \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) = (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, proof-explanation

Let's consider two random variables $X,Y$ which have n-dimensional multivariate normal distribution with mean and covariance matrix $\mu_1, \Sigma_1$ and $\mu_2, \Sigma_2$ respectively. I'm reading the [proof](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mvn-kl.html) of Kullblack - Leibler form, in the case of multivariate normal distribution. However, I cannot understand the last justification i.e. :

$$\textrm{tr}(\mu_1 \Sigma_2 \mu_1 - 2\mu_1^T \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2 + \mu_2 \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) = (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T\Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)$$

I'm thinking about this equality and I cannot understand why it holds. In fact, we know that:

$$\textrm{tr}(\mu_1 \Sigma_2 \mu_1 - 2\mu_1^T \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2 + \mu_2 \Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) = \textrm{tr}(\mu_1\Sigma_2\mu_1) - 2\textrm{tr}(\mu_1^T\Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2) + \textrm{tr}(\mu_2\Sigma_2^{-1}\mu_2)$$

but what to do next? Could you please explain to me why this equality holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the last two lines in (10). (There are several typos in your copying.)

$\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$Basically it is applying bi-linearity for the quantity within $\tr(\cdot)$:
$$
(x-y,x-y) = (x,x)-2(x,y)+(y,y)
$$
with $(a,b):=a^T\Sigma b$, and then using the fact that $\tr(x)=x$ when $x$ is a scalar. So
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left[\mu_{1}^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma_{2}^{-1} \mu_{1}-2 \mu_{1}^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma_{2}^{-1} \mu_{2}+\mu_{2}^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma_{2}^{-1} \mu_{2}\right]
=&\tr[\left(\mu_{2}-\mu_{1}\right)^{T} \Sigma_{2}^{-1}\left(\mu_{2}-\mu_{1}\right)]\\
=&\left(\mu_{2}-\mu_{1}\right)^{T} \Sigma_{2}^{-1}\left(\mu_{2}-\mu_{1}\right)
\end{align}
$$